# I need to copy only selected files and folders in PHP

Tags: php, directory, copy

I am using the following code in WINDOWS OS and PHP script, in which initially i am taking the difference of two folder structure and then the out put needs to be copied to other folder. here is the code below..

```
$source = '/var/www/html/copy1';
$mirror = '/var/www/html/copy2';
function scan_dir_recursive($dir, $rel = null) {

  $all_paths = array();
  $new_paths = scandir($dir);

  foreach ($new_paths as $path) {

    if ($path == '.' || $path == '..') {
      continue;
    }

    if ($rel === null) {
        $path_with_rel = $path;
    } else {
        $path_with_rel = $rel . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $path;
    }

    $full_path = $dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $path;
    $all_paths[] = $path_with_rel;

    if (is_dir($full_path)) {
      $all_paths = array_merge(
        $all_paths, scan_dir_recursive($full_path, $path_with_rel)
      );
    }

  }

  return $all_paths;

}
$diff_paths = array_diff(
    scan_dir_recursive($mirror),
    scan_dir_recursive($source)
);


/*$diff_path = array_diff($mirror,$original);*/
echo "<pre>Difference ";print_r($diff_paths);
    Difference of Folders Array
(
    [4] => New Folder (2)
    [5] => New Folder (2)/New Folder
    [6] => New Folder (2)/New Folder/New Folder
    [7] => New Folder (2)/New Folder/New Folder/New Text Document (2).txt
    [8] => New Folder (2)/New Folder/New Folder/New Text Document.txt
)

foreach($diff_paths as $path)
{
    echo $source1 = "var/www/html/copy2/".$path;
    echo "<br>";
    $des = "var/www/html/copy1/".$path;
    copy_recursive_dirs($source1, $des);
}

function copy_recursive_dirs($dirsource, $dirdest)
{ 
   $dir_handle=opendir($dirsource);

    mkdir($dirdest,0777);

 while(false!==($file=readdir($dir_handle)))
 {/*echo "<pre>";
  print_r($file);*/
     if($file!="." && $file!="..")
     {
         if(is_dir($dirsource.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$file)) 
         {
            //Copy the file at the same level in the destination folder
            copy_recursive_dirs($dirsource.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$file, $dirdest.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$file);

         }
         else{
            //Copy the dir at the same lavel in the destination folder
             copy ($dirsource.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$file, $dirdest.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$file);

         }
     }
  }
 closedir($dir_handle);
 return true;
}
```

Whenever I execute the script I get the difference output but do not get the other copy on second folder as per code... Pls help me in rectifying...

> **UPDATE**
>   I just want to copy the difference to
>   other folder, if theere is any other
>   way pls help me....
>
> **UPDATE:**
>   I am getting these errors,
>
> ( ! ) Warning:
>   opendir(var/www/html/copy2/New Folder
>   (2)) [function.opendir]: failed to
>   open dir: No such file or directory in
>   /var/www/html/pranav_test/syncss.php
>   on line 96
>
> ( ! ) Warning: mkdir()
>   [function.mkdir]: No such file or
>   directory in
>   /var/www/html/pranav_test/syncss.php
>   on line 99
>
> ( ! ) Warning: readdir(): supplied
>   argument is not a valid Directory
>   resource in
>   /var/www/html/pranav_test/syncss.php
>   on line 104
>
> ( ! ) Warning: closedir(): supplied
>   argument is not a valid Directory
>   resource in
>   /var/www/html/pranav_test/syncss.php
>   on line 122

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel What sort of person u r dont u have any Common sense, that after the several tries of debugging people come and ask there problem here...I f u  can help me help me out, otherwise do not demoralize others to not to help me...

Comment: How did you try? What debug techniques have tried?

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel I tried to simple copy the difference folders which didnt worked, I tried id iterating it checking whether the output is directory or not, if it is the the mkdir should execute.. and many other ways.. but none of these worked for me...

Comment: I am not begging to any one.. I am here to learn, solve the problems i am going through, If ur mind find it as begging then I am a Best Begger to learn as much as I can.... :)

Comment: well, messages is pretty clear. check file paths. in the first message it says `var/`, not `/var`, which it should be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not try to do everything at once.
Separate your task into smaller chunks.
And pass to the next one only if you had finishad and tested previous part.

First, learn to find the difference between 2 arrays:
Hardcode 2 slightly different arrays in your script and play with `array_diff()` function

Next, learn to read files from directory. Not recursive, just one.
End up with array of filenames.
Test it with `print_r()`

Now you can try to read 2 directories into arrays and compare it.
If it still not working, **debug it**: print out content of arrays, compare it with your eyes. Ask for help on SO *for this particular and certain problem* with straight and clear input data.
end up with an array of differences, **printed on the screen** to be sure it contains actual data.

Well, now you can go for the copy part. Same technique.

And then you can go for recursive directories. Same technique - double-checking and testing on every stage. Print out as much debugging information as possible.

Turn on error reporting and ensure you can see every error occurred (just make an intentional one and see). **every** filesystem operation will throw an error on failure. So, you will see the reason. And debug filesystem operations as well. Print out from inside the conditions to see if it ever got executed. Print out variable contents, function return values.

Ever got curious, what is this `$dirsource.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$file` line's **actual** value?

Comment: +1 Thanks bud for support, but my array difference is working fine.. with me, I am facing problem only with copying the difference directories...

Comment: @OM turn on error reporting and ensure you can see every error occurred (just make an intentional one and see). **every** filesystem operation will throw an error on failure. So, you will see the reason. And debug filesystem operations as well. Print out from inside the conditions to see if code ever got executed. Print out variable contents, function return values.

Comment: Thanks COL We made it.......  Its working now..... :) Thanks for ur Harsh words... It forced me to work toward my output